# In python, is there any maximum limit for word/character count to use join() keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to join keywords from list using join(). But I don't know why it is skipping some words present at the last.

Need to process text file which has lines over 10000 and only lines starting with this keyword should printed on new file.

```
import re

keywords = ['=~=~=~', 'RED', 'Starting', 'Using', 'booting', 'EXPLICIT_APPROVE', 
'communication', 'error', 'setting', 'writing', 'Drive', 'Failed', 'The', 'Disk', 'SD', 
'!!Main', 'init', 'CPU', 'writings', 'unknown', 'disks', 'SDCARD', 'Size:', 'Clearing',
 'formatting', 'creating', 'et', 'YELLOW', 'SIM', 'temperature', 'led'] 

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(keywords))

print(pattern)
```

I have attached output below please have a look.

```
re.compile('=~=~=~|RED|Starting|Using|booting|EXPLICIT_APPROVE|communication|error|setting|writing|Drive|Failed|The|Disk|SD|!!Main|init|CPU|writings|unknown|disks|SDCARD|Size:|Clearing|formatting|creating|et|YEL)
```

You can able to see from YELLOW it got striped.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? or any alternative solution to process this big txt files. It would be helpful for me.

Comment: The title is not correct. The `join` actually works.

Comment: No, there isn't (outside of resource constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roganjosh mentions in the comment, the issue is with the `__str__()` method of the class which is called in the `print` function. He has linked the details about the issue.

Running the above code gives you pattern equal to -

```
re.compile(r'=~=~=~|RED|Starting|Using|booting|EXPLICIT_APPROVE|communication|error|setting|writing|Drive|Failed|The|Disk|SD|!!Main|init|CPU|writings|unknown|disks|SDCARD|Size:|Clearing|formatting|creating|et|YELLOW|SIM|temperature|led',
re.UNICODE)
```

The `print` for some reason is only displaying a certain length of the string.

You can do this to get the full pattern as well -

```
pattern = '|'.join(keywords)
print(pattern)
```

```
=~=~=~|RED|Starting|Using|booting|EXPLICIT_APPROVE|communication|error|setting|writing|Drive|Failed|The|Disk|SD|!!Main|init|CPU|writings|unknown|disks|SDCARD|Size:|Clearing|formatting|creating|et|YELLOW|SIM|temperature|led
```

Comment: Updated my answer including mention about dup. clearning my comments as well.